# List always return a single element

Tags: list, spring-boot, arraylist, spring-security, permissions

I am working on Spring Security. I have a method called from another method. The called method is supposed to return a list with multiple elements but I always find it return only a single element in the list.

An example is this: I have 
PERMISSIONS: CREATE_EDITOR, EDIT_EDITOR, CREATE_PROFILE, EDIT_PROFILE.

ROLES: ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_PROFILE

The permissions were the first to be created, when creating ROLES, it iterates through the PERMISSIONS and return only the  PERMISSIONS that match the ROLE.

It's like the loop only runs once before saving the role. How do I make it save all the PERMISSIONS that match a ROLE?

The method that returns permissions

```
private List<Permission> myPermissions(Role role ){
        List<Permission> permissionArrayList = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        permissionArrayList = permissionRepository.findAll();
        String myRole = role.getName().split("_")[1];
        for (Permission permission: permissionArrayList) {
            if ( permission.getName().contains(myRole) ) {
                permissionArrayList.clear();
                permissionArrayList.add(permission);
                return permissionArrayList;
            }
        }
        throw new InternalServerException();
    }
```

The method that saves ROLE

```
public Role save(Role role) {
    Role myRole = new Role();
    myRole.setName(role.getName());
    myRole.setPermissions(myPermissions(role));
    roleRepository.save(myRole);
    return myRole;
}
```

Comment: of course it will only contain a single one, your are deleting everything before adding a new element. What do you think `.clear` on a collection doest?

Comment: @M. Deinum. Thanks. I was trying to clear it of the previous whole entity that was saved, had forgotten it'll clear the last inserted element.

Comment: It doesn't clear the last inserted element it clears the whole list regardless of what is in it.

Comment: If I didn't clear the list it adds all the permissions to the newly created role regardless if it matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do but I see several issues with your code:

1. You are reading from a list and concurrently modify it. That's why you need to clear it and that's why you have in the end just one item;
2. You're not saving anything, as you would be just modifying wrongly a list but you are not doing anything with it.
3. You're returning always just one permission as you have a return statement within the array cycling.
4. You're throwing InternalServer Exception if there are no permissions and that seems to be wrong.

Modifying the method in the following way will fix the issue you're seeking help for, IF your save method is working fine (for instance you should check if the permissions object returned is empty). However I would suggest you review your requirements afterwards and refactor the code.

```
private List<Permission> myPermissions(Role role ){
        List<Permission> permissions = permissionRepository.findAll();
        List<Permission> permissionsToSave = new ArrayList<Permission>();
        String myRole = role.getName().split("_")[1];
        for (Permission permission: permissions ) {
            if ( permissions.getName().contains(myRole) ) {
                permissionsToSave.add(permission);
            }
        }
        return permissionsToSave;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My immense appreciation to @AR1 and @M. Deinum. At the end of the day I have to wrap the iteration in the main method that saves (commit) to the db. The explanation of the scenario is that when the iteration method was separated it was only called once, making it to save only one matching permission object.

```
List<Permission> myPermission = new ArrayList<Permission>();
            for ( Permission permission : permissionRepository.findAll()) {
                if (permission.getName().contains(role.getName().split("_")[1])) {
                    myPermission.add(permission);
                    myRole.setName(role.getName());
                    myRole.setPermissions( myPermission );
                    roleRepository.save(myRole);
                }
            }
```